How to cancel long running asyncio.Task?
I have the following example of code:
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import functools
import time


async def run_till_first_success(tasks, timeout=None):
    results = []
    exceptions = []
    while tasks:
        try:
            async with asyncio.timeout(timeout):
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            print('timeout is catched')
            for task in tasks:
                task.cancel()  # this is not working!
            return

        # >>> this code doesn't actually matter
        for task in done:
            if task.exception():
                exceptions.append(task.exception())
            else:
                results.append(task.result())
        tasks = pending
        if results or len(pending) == 0:
            for task in pending:
                task.cancel()
            break
    if not results:
        raise exceptions[0]
    return results[0]
# <<<


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, execute):
        self.execute = execute

    async def work(self):
        return await self.execute(self._work)

    def _work(self):  # simulate long running not-async function
        print('_work started')
        time.sleep(5)
        print('_work finished')


class LibraryInterfaceClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
        self._workers = [Worker(self._execute) for _ in range(2)]

    async def use(self, timeout=1):
        tasks = {asyncio.create_task(worker.work()) for worker in self._workers}
        return await run_till_first_success(tasks, timeout)

    async def _execute(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(self._executor, functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs))


interface = LibraryInterfaceClass()
asyncio.run(interface.use())
print('run is done')

When I run it, I get the following output:
_work started
_work started
timeout is catched
run is done
_work finished
_work finished

My goal is to prevent _work finished from being printed. In another words, I want to cancel long running operations immediately after timeout occured. How to do this correctly? task.cancel() is not working in my case.
I can't modify def _work, it lies in an external library. It is a synchronous driver to external database.

The task.cancel() does not stop the thread it only stops the async coroutine. For stopping the thread we can use Event signals in Worker class for cancel long-running operations.
Here is your modified code.
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import functools
import time
import threading


async def run_till_first_success(tasks, timeout=None):
    results = []
    exceptions = []
    while tasks:
        try:
            async with asyncio.timeout(timeout):
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            print('timeout is catched')
            for task in tasks:
                task.cancel()  # Cancel the asyncio task
            return

        # >>> this code doesn't actually matter
        for task in done:
            if task.exception():
                exceptions.append(task.exception())
            else:
                results.append(task.result())
        tasks = pending
        if results or len(pending) == 0:
            for task in pending:
                task.cancel()
            break
    if not results:
        raise exceptions[0]
    return results[0]
# <<<


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, execute):
        self.execute = execute
        self.current_thread = threading.Event()  # we will use it for stopping threads

    async def work(self):
        return await self.execute(self._work)

    def _work(self):  # simulate long running not-async function
        print('_work started')
        # time.sleep(5)  # we shift it to the loop for checking cancellation status of our thread
        for _ in range(5):  # Check cancellation status periodically
            if self.current_thread.is_set():
                print('_work cancelled')
                return
            time.sleep(1)

        print('_work finished')

    def cancel(self):  # use for stopping the thread
        self.current_thread.set()


class LibraryInterfaceClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
        self._workers = [Worker(self._execute) for _ in range(2)]

    async def use(self, timeout=1):
        tasks = {asyncio.create_task(worker.work()) for worker in self._workers}
        # cancel the workers after work is done
        try:
            result = await run_till_first_success(tasks, timeout)
        finally:
            for worker in self._workers:
                worker.cancel()  # Ensure all workers receive cancel signal
        return result

    async def _execute(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(self._executor, functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs))


interface = LibraryInterfaceClass()
asyncio.run(interface.use())
print('run is done')

Output:
_work started
_work started
timeout is catched
run is done
_work cancelled
_work cancelled


Interesting, but i can't modify def _work, it lies in an external library. It is a synchronous driver to external database.

Could you share an example related to that library? Perhaps we can generate a signal to stop its execution.

actually i can't. time.sleep(5) simulates what it does quite good.

If you want to stop the function of an external library before it completes, I don't think it's possible without modifying its code, unless we can generate an error when we want to quit the function before its execution finishes.

TL;DR: there is no way in Python to cancel a running thread (without Python code which pools if it's been externally asked to be cancelled, like in the code here). But if you can run your long-running in sub-processes instead (there are differences in the overhead for starting a worker, etc...), then yes, subprocess can be killed at will given their PID.
